# flutter_downloader doesn't show notification of downloading in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I use [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) in app to allow downloading pdf files .
It is working well in Android,but in IOS,the notification of starting downloading the file doesn't appear although the file downloaded in the device.

I followed all instructions like described from Enable background mode,Add sqlite library,Configure AppDelegate

code:

```
                                       final status = await Permission.storage.request();
                                        if (status.isGranted) {

                                          // Directory _path  = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                                          //  String _localPath = _path.absolute.path + Platform.pathSeparator + 'ESPRS_Docs';

                                          var savedDir;
                                          if (Platform.isIOS) {
                                            savedDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                                          } else {
                                            savedDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
                                            // Put file in global download folder, if for an unknown reason it didn't exist, we fallback
                                            // ignore: avoid_slow_async_io
                                            if (!await savedDir.exists()) savedDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                                          }

                                          String random_no =randomAlphaNumeric(6) ;
                                          var split_name=p_title.replaceAll(" ","-");

                                           await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                                            url: p_link,
                                            savedDir: savedDir.path,
                                            fileName: "${split_name}-${random_no}.pdf",
                                            showNotification: true,
                                            saveInPublicStorage: true,
                                            openFileFromNotification: true,
                                            headers: {"auth": "Downloader"},

                                          );


                                        }else {
                                          print("Permission deined");
                                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Notification messages of download progress are only shown for Android. Behaviour differs between platforms.

```
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```